# usernamepassword@proxy-server-url:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, server, proxy

please solved this problem when i create react app npm install -g create-react-app then show this error

npm install -g create-react-app (node:15100) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://usernamepassword@proxy-server-url:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

npm install -g create-react-app (node:15100) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://usernamepassword@proxy-server-url:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)